# Python Pandas - Date Column to Column index

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

I have a table of data imported from a CSV file into a DataFrame.

The data contains around 10 categorical fields, 1 month column (in date time format) and the rest are data series.

How do I convert the date column into an index across the the column axis?

Comment: [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) does this by itself if you invoke the function with the `index_col` and `parse_dates=True`

Answer (score 37):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df.set_index('month')
```

For example:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, datetime(2011,1,1)], [2, datetime(2011,1,2)]], columns=['a', 'b'])

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   a                   b
0  1 2011-01-01 00:00:00
1  2 2011-01-02 00:00:00

In [3]: df.set_index('b')
Out[3]: 
            a
b            
2011-01-01  1
2011-01-02  2
```

Comment: Thanks Andy
Can i set the index so that the date is along the other axis? Will this group the values?

Comment: Could you give an example DataFrame which you have and what you want? I'm not sure how it makes sense to make a date column a column index... It won't group the values, this makes one column the index. :)

Comment: I want the data arranged so that each column represents 1 month. Each row in the table represents a different time series. Does that make sense? I would demonstrate with a table but I have no idea how to insert a table on this website.

Comment: A related question would be: How do I transfer an item from one index axis to another within a hierarchical index?

Comment: Look at stack() and unstack() in the documentation. For more help, give more details. (There's no special trick to inserting a table -- just uses spaces.)

Comment: add inplace=True to set_index, otherwise it does not work as expected

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem and I've just solved by `reset_index`. But you can use either `set_index` or `reset_index`:

```
df_ind = df.set_index(['A', 'B'])
```

Or

```
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know the name of the date column ahead of time and need to set the index automatically based on the time series column in the data

```
df.set_index((df.select_dtypes(include=[np.datetime64]).columns).tolist())
```